# What is the best way to make multiple get request with axios in a loop?

Tags: reactjs, request, axios

I'm having a problem making multiple request in a loop.

I'm making a react app that renders multiple components called Cards. inside each card I want to make some requests so I got this.

```
componentWillMount(){
    if(this.props.movies){ 
        let promises = []
        this.props.movies.forEach((item, i) => {
            console.log(item)
            let movieUrl = `http://localhost:3000/movies/${item}`
            promises.push(axios.get(movieUrl))
        })

        axios.all(promises).then(res => console.log(res))
    }
}
```

Movies is an array that I get from the father component.
so apparently is working because I get results but tit is always with the last element of the last card. Here is an image:

[image: Look, Even the item is changing (those tt....) I always get the last responde, what can I do ?]

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using `forEach` when you really need to `map` and build the url with `item.imdbID` instead of `item`

```
componentWillMount(){
    if(this.props.movies){ 
        const promises = this.props.movies.map(item => {
            const movieUrl = `http://localhost:3000/movies/${item.imdbID}`
            console.log(movieUrl)
            return axios.get(movieUrl)
        )
        Promise.all(promises).then(results => console.log(results))
    }
}
```

Edit1: removed async/await due to incompatible build configuraton
Edit2: used `item.imdbID` instead of `item` and logged urls

Comment: Thanks for your answer, damnnn another error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined"

Comment: Ok, your build setup does not support async/await, I edited the answer to avoid using async/await

Comment: Now works but Still returning only Sharknados jajaja, OMG yes my setup is something with webpack I don't undrstand correctly, is there any way or dependence to use await/async ?

Comment: If I understand your screenshot, the `item` is an object and you should use `item.imdbID` when building the url. For async await, you should avoid using it with little knowing about how webpack works, this thing is quite obscure and you will lose some time ^^. You can still use `create-react-app` which is nothing less than pre-configured webpack to get started with a properly configured react env

Comment: yes, definetively is something with my webpack set up, I'll try to solve it. Thanks bro

Comment: No problem. Did the `item.imdbID` change work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await`. Look:

```
async componentWillMount(){
    if(this.props.movies){ 
        const results = []
        this.props.movies.forEach((item, i) => {
            const movieUrl = `http://localhost:3000/movies/${item}`
            const result = await axios.get(movieUrl)
            results.push(result)
        })
        // console.log(results)
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives me this error: " await is a reserved word (23:28)"

Comment: Thanks @Tiago Alves

Comment: You're welcome. If it solves the question, please mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: No, I'm still having the problem T_T what can I do ?

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. So, probably your webpack setup doesn't allow the use of async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bluebird's [Promise.mapSeries](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html)?

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'
componentWillMount(){
    if(this.props.movies){ 
        Promise.resolve(this.props.movies)
            .mapSeries(item => axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/movies/${item}`))
            .then(movies => console.log(movies))
    }
}
```

Comment: @Deivbid Are you sure this.props.movies contains the correct values?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you can see 3 of them in the image, that log shows me that effectively every string is in its card, the problem is the request is like just make request to the last one. I think the solution has to be something with await or async but It doesn't work for me :( can I set up my webpack or something ?

Comment: @Deivbid The async/await solution basically does the same thing, so if the values in this.props.movies are correct, then the problem is probably serverside, in your http://localhost:3000/movies/:imdbID route.

But if you do want to enable async/await either way, [this](https://gist.github.com/thejmazz/067295d9fb8b22c77be0) is how you would do it.